# adView cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, admob

It shows an two error 
1) when i am pointing my cursor to R.id.adView. At adView it says "adView cannot be resolved or is not a field" 
  2) In second line of adrequest at last word .build(), when i am take my cursor to .build() it says "The method build() is undefined for the type AdRequest.Builder"

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

In XML file..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity"
 tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

And in Graphical layout it says "The following classes could not be found:
- com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView (Change to android.view.View, Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class) "

Please help me and suggest best as i am now in trouble...

Comment: be sure You have used the com.google.android.gms.ads and not the old admob package. Second possibility: have You declared all in Your manifest?

Comment: thanks but, how to include Google play service library?